# How to remove kernel from ubuntu built on openvz which hasn't completely installed

Tags: 14.04, server, kernel, openvz

I tried to upgrade ubuntu kernel in my openvz vps but failed then I realized that OpenVZ does not allow to upgrade kernel, then I tried to remove the new kernel, but failed, with following message:

```
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic (3.13.0-74.118) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-74-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-74-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.13.0-74-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-74-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing crda (1.1.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing iw (3.4-1) ...
Removing os-prober (1.63ubuntu1) ...
Removing wireless-regdb (2013.02.13-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing dmsetup (2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2) ...
Removing grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.6) ...
Removing grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7) ...
Removing grub2-common (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7) ...
Removing grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7) ...
Removing grub-common (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7) ...
Removing libfuse2:amd64 (2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1) ...
Removing libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone know how to completely remove this kernel? Or I have to reinstall a fresh one?